# How to use Thread.Abort() properly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadabortexception, thread-abort

What can cause issues when thread is aborted?

I need to use `Thread.Abort()` in my code because the thread runs complex code that have a lot of loops, objects and conditions.

I know that `Thread.Abort()` can lead to deadlock when using `Monitor`, also it can prevent resources from being released, but I can handle these problems.

I use `IDisposable`/`using` pattern or catch `ThreadAbortException` to guarantee that all resources are released and asynchronous operations are stopped.

The application seems to works fine now. But, since the code is pretty complex, I'm not sure if there could be some rare cases when aborting the thread can lead to memory leaks or unhandled exceptions.

Is there any .net classes (e.g. `FileStream`, `Dictionary`) that can cause problems if thread is aborted when their code are executed? Or some other issues that I should be aware of?

Comment: I'm not so sure that your thread really dies when you ask for it.

Comment: You should better try cooperative cancellation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

Comment: I do know about `CancellationToken` but it's gonna be a lot of work to refactor the code to cancel it quick enough

Comment: @MarcoSalerno it dies, I've checked for it.

Comment: Also `Thread.Abort()` can leave the .NET run-time in an invalid state - it means that you cannot trust any of the remaining threads to behave properly after aborting a thread. It's for that reason that aborting threads **should only ever be done when crashing out of an app**.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for that note, can you provide more info?

Comment: @781F - Have a read of http://blog.peterritchie.com/Thread.Abort-is-a-Sign-of-a-Poorly-Designed-Program/

Comment: That article is wrong about lock statements - it's out of date. `lock` now uses a new overload of `Monitor.Enter` which is safe to a thread abort happening. Other types of lock, however, are not.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `Thread.Abort` is that your `ThreadAbortException` can be thrown between *any* two instructions (almost).

If you take some very simple code like:

```
public void M()
{
    using (CreateThing())
    {
    }
}

public IDisposable CreateThing() => null;
```

And look at the [generated C# and IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBEJinANjASQDsYIFsBjCAgWwAdcIaITYBLAeyIB8ABABgAEvAIwBuALAAoXgGZhAJkEBhQQG9pgrcPm8ALIICyACgCU6zdqsDBx5UlgQAKgAs2RAOZnTlq1o1SftoAvr6CoYHaYXKCBOhsyHQcyFDAjCoOpK7uXuYAvAB8gkR4uJJSwUA==):

```
public void M()
{
    IDisposable disposable = CreateThing();
    try
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that there's a couple of instructions between `CreateThing` being called, and it entering the `try` block. There's a small window of opportunity where, if `Thread.Abort` is called right then, your object will *not* be disposed.

So using `IDisposable` and `using` does **not** guarantee that your resources get freed in the face of `Thread.Abort`.

There is a very good reason why `Thread.Abort` was removed from .NET Standard, and why you should use `CancellationToken` instead.

You should use `CancellationToken`, and your code should check whether it's been cancelled (using `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`) at suitable, safe points.

---

As an aside, `lock` statements use an [overload of `Monitor.Enter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.enter?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Monitor_Enter_System_Object_System_Boolean__) which returns a boolean saying whether the lock was actually acquired, and:

```
lock (lockObject)
{
}
```

compiles to:

```
bool lockTaken = false;
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(lockObject, ref lockTaken);
}
finally
{
    if (lockTaken)
        Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
}
```

to avoid exactly this problem.

However, you don't get this luxury when using any other synchronization methods - only `lock` - and so you can easily deadlock.

Comment: > So using `IDisposable` and `using` does not guarantee that your resources get freed in the face of `Thread.Abort`.

But if I do it in finalizer and using GC.Collect, then I should be fine?

Comment: It depends what your `Dispose` method is doing. Not everything can be done by the finalizer - if your `Dispose` method unsubscribes from an event / observable, or releases a lock, or does anything which *isn't* freeing an unmanaged resource, then you're still in trouble.

Comment: (Also, you need to do a combination of a couple of `GC.Collects` and a `WaitForPendingFinalizers` to wait for finalizers to run, and the full GCs it needs are *expensive*)

Comment: Basically you're playing with fire by relying on Thread.Abort. Various people have discovered this for themselves over the years. You may think you're clever enough to solve all the problems, but because this issue is inherently racy, there are problems which will *only* occur once a year in production, and you will not be able to debug or fix them.

Comment: You should have a read of [Eric Lippert's reply to a question about Thread.Abort()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560567/106159): `Thread.Abort is at best indicative of bad design, possibly unreliable, and extremely dangerous. It should be avoided at all costs`

Comment: @MatthewWatson That is also a very good and valid read, and probably deserves its own answer here (or perhaps this should be closed as a duplicate)